# Uncheck checkbox with javascript when the checkbox is disabled is not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I've this situation:

In grid I have TextBox and on changing text in the TextBox I uncheck checkbox in the grid with javascript.

When the checkbox is enabled, everything is working correctly:
Value in the code behind for `CheckBox1.Checked = false`, but when the checkbox is disabled value in the code behind for `CheckBox1.Checked = true` (Checkbox is render as unchecked by the browser).

Someone ideas ?

I unchecked the checbox with line of code like this:

```
document.getElementById("Checkbox1").checked = false;
```

This is happen on checkbox.OnChange

Comment: I find a solution using hidden fields. Like I said the problem was in ASP framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("<%=Checkbox1.ClientId%>").checked = false;
```

Comment: The problem is not in the java script. I have loop through all the elements and I do element[i].checked=false in the right case. Like I said the browser render the checkbox as unchecked. But in the server side the value of CheckBox1.Checked is still true.

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery here. It always works.

```
//Checking a checkbox.
$("#CheckBox1").prop('checked', true); // or false to uncheck checkbox.     
// Check whether Checkbox is checked or not?
if($("#CheckBox1").prop("checked")){ 
  alert('checked');
}else{
  alert('unchecked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how it doing using jquery 
$("#<%=Checkbox1.ClientID %>").prop("checked",false);